# How to make pointcut expressions advise methods of beans that extend classes that are defined in third-party library?

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I have a Spring bean defined like this:

```
package org.behrang.sample;

import foo.AbstractThirdPartyClass;

@Component
public class SampleBean extends AbstractThirdPartyClass<Input, Output> {

    @Override
    public Optional<Output> process(Input input) {

    }

}
```

The `AbstractThirdPartyClass` class is defined in a third-party library named `foo`.

I want to implement an advice that applies to all methods in the 
`org.behrang.sample` package, so I have implemented something like this:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class SampleAspect {

    @Before("execution(public * org.behrang.sample..*.*(..))")
    public void sampleBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {

    }
}
```

However this is not advising `SampleBean::process(Input)`. If I remove the `extends AbstractThirdPartyClass<Input, Output>`
part, then the `process` method is advised.

Is there an elegant way to workaround this problem? For example, I can define an interface in `org.behrang.sample` with one method like this:

```
public interface Sampler<I, O> {
    public Optional<O> process(I input);
}
```

And make the SampleBean implement it too. But this is way too ugly and anti-DRY.

Also I have enabled AOP using `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)` as manu beans defined in this project are not implementing any interfaces.

Comment: I am not a Spring user, but kind of an AspectJ expert. Even so, I have no immediate explanation. What you do should work. But I know that in order to apply Spring AOP (not AspectJ!) to classes not extending interfaces, you need _cglib_ on your classpath. Maybe that one is missing?

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look. I did some research on my own as well and looks like for at least some advanced features, Spring's Maven or Gradle build file should be configured to use the AspectJ compiler altogether.

Comment: Regarding CGLIB, it is included. In fact, Spring [repackages](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cglib/package-summary.html) it and it is always included in the classpath.

Comment: Then please share an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) including a Maven POM on GitHub so as to make the problem reproduceable. I think there are many variables here and the Spring experts - or even a Spring noob like I, if you are lucky - can easily see what is going wrong if they see the same problem as you.

Comment: Will do. Have to go back to work to reproduce the problem.